# Custom template for shared taxonomy Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I have the current setup for my custom post type and taxonomy:

**custom post type:** article
**custom taxonomy:** service-type

the **service-type** is shared with another custom posts in the website and right now I have the following URLs for the articles:

*/articles/*

*/articles/%category%/%postname%/*

But when I try to access this URL: */articles/%category%/* I got redirected to the home page. But if I use the normal URL */service-type/%category%/* I can view the page.

What I need is a template file to load a layout specifically for this page ***/articles/%category%/*** but I don't know what the template file should be called and I don't know if this will affect the other custom posts.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress won't readily let you have your detail pages (single posts) be this format: /articles/%category%/%postname%/ because that post could feasibly be in another category/taxonomy as well. Meaning, which URL is "right" here? /articles/stuff/post-name OR /articles/things/post-name? See what I mean?

However, your question is in regards to a template for /articles/%category%/. When creating an custom taxonomy, it will normally want to generate the URL like so:

website.com/custom-cat/

Which is controlled by archive.php and more specific templates (see [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)), but you can make the URL more like you want: website.com/articles/custom-cat by adding this to register_taxonomy $args:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articles/custom-cat' )
```

Hopefully this helps put you in the right direction.